# Which will be the experimental error in this ripple tank experiment?

Tags: experimental-physics, double-slit-experiment, error-analysis

I am having some issues while setting my experimental error in a ripple tank experiment where we are studying the interference in multiple slit.

[image: Experiment]

I already know that it is not the most accurate experiment (The resolution is a bit better than in the photo but it has been downgrade while uploading), but as you can see the maxima interference line has some width, which makes a bit difficult to establish where the middle is, so how can I establish an error from that? The measure app that I am using has 0,1º precision.
I have thought that I can take 3 or 4 maxima lines and do least squares and get the error from that. What do you think?